# Difference between [sqlite] and [sqlite3] tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request, synonym-request

Is there any useful difference between the tags [sqlite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sqlite) and [sqlite3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sqlite3)? Could one either be removed or made a synonym of the other?

The wiki tag description for both tags is the same:

> SQLite is a software library that implements a self-contained, serverless, zero-configuration, transactional SQL database engine.

The [sqlite3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sqlite3) has no synonyms but [sqlite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sqlite) has [sqlitedatabase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sqlitedatabase) as a solitary synonym.

Comment: Normally version tags are used for questions about features specific for that version. If that usage guidance is added to sqlite3 I see no problem with it.

Comment: @rene how does that work when someone asking a question knows it applies to (say) version 3 _because that's the version they are using_, but doesn't know if it's exclusive to that version?

Comment: Sqlite has been on version 3 for the past 12 years.  It is not useful, a synonym is appropriate.

Comment: @HansPassant So in your line of reasoning  sqlite3 should be a synonym of sqlite, right?

Comment: @roaima yes, that is what is hard with version specific tags. I'm not into sqlite to understand if the difference is relevant or not. Based on Hans his comment I assume it is not.

Comment: @HansPassant given the static nature of the sqlite versioning I think it might make more sense to replace the [tag:sqlite3] tag with [tag:sqlite] rather than leave it as a potential source of confusion and ambiguity (synonym or otherwise). I've only got 200 on this stackexchange so I can't affect the tags directly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that the synonym should be enough, I can see no reasons to keep the specific version tag. Although there [were](https://www.sqlite.org/34to35.html) some changes which might indicate breaking changes in functional behaviour, but it still is 3.x.

According to the SQLite [versioning](https://www.sqlite.org/versionnumbers.html) page:

> The rate of enhancement for SQLite over the previous five years
>   (2010-2015) is approximately 6 increments of Y per year. The numbering
>   format used by for SQLITE_VERSION_NUMBER and
>   sqlite3_libversion_number() allows versions up to 3.999.999, which is
>   more than enough for the planned end-of-support date for SQLite in
>   2050. However, the current tarball naming conventions only reserve two digits for the Y and so the naming format for downloads will need to
>   be revised in about 2030.

it will remain the same for the far term future.