# Merge [sqlite] and [sqlite3]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request, synonym-request

[sqlite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sqlite) and [sqlite3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sqlite3) seem to be synonyms in practice.

A few observations:

- The tag descriptions start off with the same plagiarised paragraph and neither contains any usage guidance about when to prefer one over the other.
- SQLite 3 was first released in mid-2004, and the project has been on some sort of version 3.x.x ever since, so the two tags aren't really being used in practice to help identify the version being asked about.
- There's both a Python module and an Android tool called `sqlite3`, but a quick look over the [top 50 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sqlite3?sort=votes&pageSize=50) in the tag shows that the tag isn't being reliably used to refer to either of them.

In the absence of either any actual difference in meaning between the two tags in current practice, or any useful difference in meaning I can imagine between them in principle, it seems to me that it'd make sense to merge them. Thoughts?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/325744/difference-between-sqlite-and-sqlite3-tags

Comment: There are some 38k posts, and 11k watchers, and top users page is filled ... still no one has proposed the synonym ._.

Comment: @BhargavRao Interesting. Maybe someone should shoot a chat message at the top  5 or 10 users and ask if any of them would like to weigh in here. Possibly some of them simply avoid proposing synonyms full stop? I recall that the merely synonymising tags without merging them is [horribly broken](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/340407/1709587) in some way, the details of which escape me now, and have always been unsure on whether it's actually better than doing nothing and waiting for a mod to get on board.